# PowerToys for Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, download

**I have Tweak UI, but it seems to be the wrong version, because everything I change, goes back to the way it was before once I reboot the computer.

I tried to find that second version to download, but I keep finding the first one (and I don't know which one I do have, 2.0 or 2.10).

If somebody could give me the links for downloading both, I would be grateful.
**

Comment: sorry can't help, don't understand how this google thingy works

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft PowerToys for Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx)

[Tweek UI direct link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/c/a/fca6767b-9ed9-45a6-b352-839afb2a2679/TweakUiPowertoySetup.exe)

Comment: These links are both for the same version, unfortunately, for the one I already have...